# A geometry (circles and tangents) problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, power-of-the-point

In the following figure[image]

There is a circle with centre at origin. **D** and **E** are two tangent points of the circle from point **C**. **FGHI** is a rectangle and it is given that **DG=5** and **GI=4**. And I have to find the length of **EH**

I tried solving this question could not solve it. Is the question correct? If it is please provide the solution.

Comment: Point B has nothing to do with the question. Actually I drew it on a tool and made this typo

Comment: $DG$ being equal to $5$ there are not intersection $F$ (according to the graphic the point $G$ must be close to the point $C$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extend $HF$ to cut the circle second time at $J$. By the power of the point $H$ with respect to the circle we have $$HE^2 = HF\cdot HJ = HF\cdot (HF+2DG) =4\cdot 14 $$

so $$HE = 2\sqrt{14}$$